# storing transactions in an OrderedList

Tags: java

I'm a Java noob so please bear with me.

I'm having an issue with a java project I have to complete.  We have to sort a list of 10,000 customer transactions, pick the top three customers that spent the most, then give five random customers gift cards, five of them starting at $20 and ending at $100, increasing in $20 increments.  So far I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("Transactions.txt"));
BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    Scanner trans = null;
    try {
        trans = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new       FileReader("Transactions.txt")));
        trans.useDelimiter("s*");
        while (trans.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(trans.next());

        }
    }
        finally {
            if (trans !=null) {
                trans.close();
```

I'm confused as to how I would put this information into an OrderedList so it'll sort them in ascending order according to the amount they spent.

EDIT:  Here are some lines from the transaction.txt file:

Order # Date    First name  Middle Initial  Last name   Address City    State    Zip    Email   Transaction Amount
1   8/26/2012   Kristina    H   Chung   947 Martin Ave. Muncie  CA  46489   khchung@business.com     $593 
2   11/16/2012  Paige   H   Chen    15 MainWay Rd.  Dallas  HI  47281   phchen@business.com  $516 
3   11/10/2012  Sherri  E   Melton  808 Washington Way  Brazil  CA  47880   semelton@business.com    $80 
4   9/20/2012   Gretchen    I   Hill    56 Washington Dr.   Atlanta FL  47215   gihill@business.com  $989 
5   3/11/2012   Karen   U   Puckett 652 Maplewood Ct.   Brazil  FL  46627   kupuckett@business.com   $826

My apologies, but I have no idea how to make this look neat.

Comment: This cannot be all your code. I think you accidentally cut it off at the bottom.

Comment: Actually this is all I have so far.  What I cut off is just closing the brackets I left open here.  I'm sorry I can't provide a lot of detail in what I'm trying to do, but I'm really confused and have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: Well your first problem seems to be with just reading in the data. Are you sure this line: `trans.useDelimiter("s*");` does what you think?

Comment: Well there are 9 separate fields I need to read in the file, so I'm assuming that line puts a space in between each field.  If not then my issue's probably a lot bigger than I think it is.  I have to take all nine fields and store them in the array so I can use them to display who spent the most, how much, and their email addresses.

Comment: To begin with, it doesn't "put" a space anywhere. It sets the delimiter for the `Scanner`, which determines what `trans.next()` will  return. Now, I think you meant to use this `trans.useDelimiter("\\s+");`, which will match 1 or more spaces (also tabs and \n) between words.

Comment: Now, we can't just write the code for you! Since you should have your `Scanner` set up properly (with my above comment), see if you can write some working code to store the data, in whatever form you were told to do so with.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for.  Maybe explaining what I want better will help you help me.  Our professor wants us to read the file of 10K customers and store the 9 fields in a structure (I'm choosing an ArrayOrderedList).  We had to create a class giving each field a variable (already done that).  We then have to create a main class that takes the info in the structure, determines the top three spenders along with five random people to give giftcards to, and writes them to an output file.

Comment: by the way I understand you can't write the code for me and I'm not expecting you to.  I'm just really confused as to what I'm doing so far is correct or not and if I'm utilizing what I should properly.  I thank you for taking the time to help out a complete noob.

Comment: Well, if you know how to do everything else, and your person Class works properly, then I can write some partial code for the selection part and input. I'll leave the output to you.

Comment: Yes that would be beneficial since the input code is what I'm having the most problems with.  I think I'll be fine when it comes to spitting out the information since we've done that in class before. 

Thanks again for your time, Azar.

Comment: Speaking of time, I'm pretty short on it right now. Can you wait until tomorrow, and also post a few lines of `Transactions.txt`?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot.  This project's due in two hours and I've spent the last three trying to work out the input.  If time is an issue for you I completely understand.  I'll go back and edit my question to post a few lines from the txt file.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have time right now. Hopefully someone else can help you out. Good luck!